# Application Blocked By Java security

Tags: java-8, vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

See screenshot below.

After installing JRE 1.8 and I am not able to access VNC and whenever I do I get error(Please find the error in attachment)

I don't want the site to be added to the Exception List. Is there any another solution?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [Java Security page](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml). Try modifying your security levels.

Comment: You need to either sign the application with a (not-self-signed) certificate or add the site to the exception list. Why don't you want to add it to the list?

Comment: It is not just this website ,there is a huge list of websites and also the list is dynamic